# I have 2 Tables and i want to sum odd numbers

Tags: c

My code does 2 tables where i input the data and i want to sum the odd numbers of those 2 tables

```
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
for(j=0;j<m;j++)
if(i==j)
s=s+a[i][j];
return(s);
```

How do i add only the odd numbers?

Comment: Your current code only adds numbers on the diagonal in *one* table (where is the second table?), and there is a vastly faster way of adding only those numbers on the diagonal, if that was indeed attempted.

Comment: @AvicT Where are there two tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if an integer is odd like this:

```
if (n % 2 == 1) {
    // odd number
} else {
    // even number
}
```

The [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) `%` returns the remainder of `n` divided by `2`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I changed it back and explained the code.